# App Engine Datastore Indexes: Entry Count blank?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the Google App Engine Admin Console, under Datastore Indexes, all of my indexes are listed as Serving. However, a lot of them are blank in the Index Entry Count and Index Storage columns. And yet still, those same indexes have a specified size on the Datastore Statistics page. What does all this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Datastore Indexes and Datastore Statistics get updated separately, so you should check the "last updated" value in each of the screens and see if they seem to match or not.

For example, one of my apps currently says:

- Statistics: Last updated: 1 day, 13:14:07 ago
- Indexes: 1 day, 13:15:12 ago

Comment: Mine says "15:07:12 ago" ,but there are still some indexes with no indexed values, but there are dozens of entries in the table.

Comment: I am seeing this as well.  I've vacuumed and updated indexes from AppCfg and I still have a blank index count, which is making any queries that rely on it fail as if it did not exist.

Comment: Same here: index showing up as empty (Size --) and all queries failing.

Comment: Do the errors for the queries say that the index is not present, or not ready to serve?